# Dataview - add item

Tags: extjs

I want to add item into a dataview component. I want different html for the newly created item. What is the best way to achieve?

Is it creating a new member function of the template for empty id the right way to go or there  are better ways?

Comment: Do you mean Sencha Touch and the **Ext.DataView**? You could use the _tpl:_ of the **Ext.DataView** and customize the appearance of your data by passing it an Ext.XTemplate.

Comment: Your approach seems OK to me.